# OnActivityResult() is not called in Android Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to install CA certificates from a class in android. This is what I am doing.

```
//File1.java - This is a non-activity

ArrayList<String> CACertsList = new ArrayList<String>();
CACertsList.add(encodedCACert1);
CACertsList.add(encodedCACert2);

Context context = _serviceInstance.getServiceContext();
Intent intent = new Intent(context, CACertInstallActivity.class);
intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
intent.putExtra( "CERTDATA", CACertsList );
context.startActivity(intent);
```

And the actual activity

```
public class CACertInstallActivity extends Activity
{

   @Override
   public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
   {
       super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

       Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
       ArrayList<String> CACerts = bundle.getStringArrayList("CERTDATA");

       for( int i = 0; i < CACerts.size(); i++ )
       {
        try
        {
            // Convert base64encoded Cert data to byte array and converting it into X509 Certificate format
            byte[] certData = Base64.decode( CACerts.get(i) );
            CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(certData);
            X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)certFactory.generateCertificate(in);

            // Start the install intent for the cert
            Intent intent = KeyChain.createInstallIntent();
            intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP );
            intent.putExtra( KeyChain.EXTRA_CERTIFICATE, cert.getEncoded() );
            intent.putExtra( KeyChain.EXTRA_NAME, cert.getIssuerDN().getName() );
            this.startActivityForResult(intent,2);
        }
        catch (CertificateException e1) 
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e1) 
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



@Override
protected void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data )
{
   if( resultCode == RESULT_OK )
   {
        // Success
   }
   else
   {
        // Failed
   }

   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```

Manifest declaration

```
 <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden" android:name=".activity.CACertInstallActivity"/>
```

I have two problems. One is when I am installing multiple certs, only one of the cert installation prompt is coming up. Another is the onActivityResult method is never called. Can anyone figure out the error that I am doing?

Also, the createInstallIntent does return value

```
   * <p>When used with {@link Activity#startActivityForResult},
 * {@link Activity#RESULT_OK} will be returned if a credential was
 * successfully installed, otherwise {@link
 * Activity#RESULT_CANCELED} will be returned.
```

Comment: is KeyChain Activity (the one you started with startActivityForResult) singleInstance? can you also put android manifest?

Comment: The keychain activity is one that is provided by KeyChain API @android.security.KeyChain

Comment: As I guess, removing the flags that you add (the line that starts with intent.addFlags(...)) should fix the problem. If it works, I will explain the reason :)

Comment: @Semih Removing the flags on CACertInstallActivity intent didnt make it call onActivityForResult.  Removing the flag on File1.java caused an exception.

Answer (score 2):

For the onActivityResult not being called, try changing `context.startActivity(intent);` for `context.startActivityForResult(intent);`

Comment: There is no startActivityForResult available for the ServiceContext

Answer (score 1):

It's maybe late, but the `startActivityForResult(intent, 2)` is not called from the Context, but from an Activity.

So from a class which extends wether **AppCompatActivity** or **Activity**, you just need to call :

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

Now, about the error you are getting, you maybe solved this, but you have to wait into the `onActivityResult` before starting another Intent to install the following certificate.

Also remove the flags from your intent.

From my side I basically made a queue ( a list) which takes all certificate, and then process this list, each time you go on the `onActivityResult`, you just launch the next certificate intent installation.

The only problem I have now, is that the `onActivityResult` function is not called if someone click on "**Cancel**" button. Which shouldn't be the case normally.